# Reading properties file from superclass project

Tags: java, eclipse, properties-file

So I have an Eclipse project, with an abstract class `A`. `A` has a method `doStuff()` that reads from a properties file `./resources/stuff.properties`. I have a second project, containing a class `B` that extends `A`. When I try to call `B.doStuff()`, I get a `FileNotFoundException`, since `stuff.properties` is in the `A` project, not the `B` project. How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you will have the project as a .jar library. You can open the properties file relative to the .jar's directory.

You can get the directory where the jar is using the following code

```
A.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().toURI()
```